# RegEx to capture repeating fields?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a buffer I'm trying to parse with regular expressions.

Here's an example of the buffer:

```
DATA#ALPHAONE;BETATWO.CHARLIETHREE!
```

The format is: The buffer always starts with "DATA#", as a literal header.
After that it will have one-or-more text-fields separated by either a semicolon, period or exclamation.

My Regex pattern (in C#) so far is:

```
string singleFieldPattern = "(?'Field'.*?)(?'Separator'[;.!])";
string fullBufferPattern = "(?'Header'DATA#)(" + singleFieldPattern + ")+";
```

The problem comes when I try to dump the data that matched:

```
Regex response = new Regex(fullBufferPattern);
string example = "DATA#ALPHAONE;BETATWO.CHARLIETHREE!";

Debug.WriteLine("RegEx Matches?: {0}", response.IsMatch(example));  
foreach (Match m in response.Matches(example))
{
    foreach(string s in new string[]{"Header", "Field", "Separator"}) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", s, m.Groups[s]);
    }
}
```

The only output is:

```
RegEx Matches?: True
Header : DATA#
Field : CHARLIETHREE
Separator : !
```

I intended the output to be:

```
RegEx Matches?: True
Header : DATA#
Field : ALPHAONE
Separator : ;
Field : BETATWO
Separator : .
Field : CHARLIETHREE
Separator : !
```

My expression did not get the earlier fields, `ALPHAONE` and `BETATWO` (and their Separators of `;` and `.`) as I intended.  It only captured the last field (`CHARLIETHREE`).

How can I get all the parts that matched `singleFieldPattern`?

---

I've simplified my data format above for question purposes, but since some people want the real-data, here is much closer to the actual data:

*(Note:  values in **[ ]** are single-bytes that are unprintable, and spaces are for clarity only.)*

Example:

```
[SYN] % SYSNAMScanner[ACK]; BAUDRATE57600[ACK]; CTRLMODEXON[ACK];
```

**Translation:**
   The System Name (SYSNAM) is "Scanner"
   The baud rate is 57,600
   The Flow Control is XON

Comment: MUST you use a regex? Because otherwise, string.Split() would get you what you need.

Comment: @hometoast: My actual buffer is considerably more complex, and requires a Regex.  But for question-purposes, I reduced it to this minimal example.

Comment: Unless it's just a side effect of you reducing complexity for the question, that is one _weird_ data format. I don't suppose you can change the source to make it be in a more ordinary format?

Comment: I don't control the source data, unfortunately.  If you want a glimpse of the real data, I'll edit the question in a minute.

Comment: @hometoast:  Its a shame you deleted your answer, because the "Captures" property turns out to be exactly what I needed.  I'll happily upvote and accept your answer if you undelete it or re-post.   The other answers involving Linq are also effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying this in VB (because that's what I have open), but consider iterating the Capture for the group:

```
  For Each m As Capture In response.Match(example).Groups("Field").Captures
     Debug.WriteLine(m.Value)
  Next
```

gives me

```
ALPHAONE
BETATWO
CHARLIETHREE
```

Comment: The `Captures` element of Groups was exactly what I needed.  I just overlooked it before.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a bit of LINQ, you can do this:

```
string data = "DATA#ALPHAONE;BETATWO.CHARLIETHREE!";
var fullBufferPattern = @"(?<header>DATA#)(?<fields>.+)[;.!]";
var fieldPattern = @"(?<field>[^;.!]+)[;.!]?";

var fields = Regex.Matches(data, fullBufferPattern)
                    .OfType<Match>()
                    .SelectMany(
                        m =>
                        Regex.Matches(m.Groups["fields"].Value, fieldPattern)
                             .OfType<Match>())
                    .Select(m => m.Groups["field"].Value).ToArray();
```

The variable `fields` will have:

```
ALPHAONE    
BETATWO
CHARLIETHREE
```

**Edit:** To reproduce you `Debug` output, use:

```
string data = "DATA#ALPHAONE;BETATWO.CHARLIETHREE!";
var fullBufferPattern = @"(?<header>DATA#)(?<fields>([^;.!]+[;.!])+)";
var fieldPattern = @"(?<field>[^;.!]+)(?<separator>[;.!])";

var groups = Regex.Matches(data, fullBufferPattern)
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Select(
                      m =>
                      new
                      {
                          Header = m.Groups["header"],
                          Fields = Regex.Matches(m.Groups["fields"].Value, fieldPattern)
                                        .OfType<Match>()
                                        .Select(f => new
                                            {
                                                Field = f.Groups["field"],
                                                Separator = f.Groups["separator"]
                                            })
                      });

foreach (var element in groups)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Header : {0}", element.Header);
    foreach (var field in element.Fields)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Field : {0}", field.Field);
        Debug.WriteLine("Separator : {0}", field.Separator);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Header : DATA#
Field : ALPHAONE
Separator : ;
Field : BETATWO
Separator : .
Field : CHARLIETHREE
Separator : !
```

Answer (score 3):

This bit of LINQ will pair together the fields and separators from your regex:

```
var ms = response.Matches(example);
foreach (Match m in ms)
{
    string header = m.Groups["Header"].Value;
    Debug.WriteLine("Header : " + header);
    var pairs = m.Groups["Field"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Zip(
                    m.Groups["Separator"].Captures.Cast<Capture>(),
                    (f, s) => new { Field = f.Value, Separator = s.Value });
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(pair.ToString());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Header : DATA#
{ Field = ALPHAONE, Separator = ; }
{ Field = BETATWO, Separator = . }
{ Field = CHARLIETHREE, Separator = ! }
```

Answer (score 1):

so you want to get all values that follow the Header Pattern or the single Field Pattern?

```
"(?'Header'^DATA#)|(?'Field'.*?)(?'Separator'[;.!])"
```

that should do fine, not sure what else you have that you're parsing though.